# KeyCloak : How to create readonly attributes for a user

Tags: keycloak

I'm new to keycloak.

I want to make few attributes of user as readonly (even for admin user).

Now, I could able to create attributes but didn't found option to change them into readonly attributes.

Tried several ways but nothing worked good for me. Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is your use case and what kind of info you want to store, currently how you are allowing user to access user attributes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem (I want birthdate, firstname and lastname imported from an IDP to be readonly). My solution is to store the attribute with a different name.
For example, if I want my birthdate to be readonly, I store the value in attribute `birthdate_readonly` and I set the client's mapper for `birthdate` to send `birthdate_readonly` attribute's value. 
In fact `birthdate_readonly` can be overwritten but at least it is hidden.

If anyone has a true solution to make the attribute readonly, I'll be glad to know. Maybe with SPI or authentication flow scripts :/